# Correct way to install drivers for a laptop?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, graphics-card, dell-inspiron

I have Dell Inspiron 15 3<sup>rd</sup> generation laptop. It has an AMD Radeon 7670m GPU.

The Dell drivers site has mentioned newer drivers for some hardware like CPU, AMD GPU, Intel GPU, touchpad, etc. 
In what order should I install the drivers so as to have no problems?
Specifically I am confused as to whether I should install the AMD driver or the Intel HD Graphics driver first?
And also about CPU drivers or GPU drivers first?

The Dell site does not give any information on this regard.

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/questions/582484

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which you install most drivers is irrelevant for the functioning, except:

1. Chipset drivers. Install these first since they may change base settings influencing PCI(e) address space. Rarely a problem these days, but quite important with old computers.
2. NIC drivers are often second, so that you can actually download drivers to the laptop. This is merely a matter of convenience.
3. Graphics next. Also just as a matter of convenience. Having a bit more real estate than just 640x480 really helps on most driver pages, including on Dell's driver site.

In your case, I would check which hardware you have before you start downloading any drivers. Go to [Dell's website](http://www.dell.com/) and use your service tag to discover precisely which hardware you have in your laptop. Does it have **only** the build in Intel GPU? Or does it have a regular Intel CPU without GPU and a dedicated AMD GPU? Does it have both? Do you want some optimus like installation? Etc etc.

Download the right drivers **after** you know what you have and what you want.

Comment: it has both Intel & ATI GPU's as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a Radeon, you don´t need the Intel HD drivers, and vice versa. The order of installing CPU, GPU, and touchpad drivers is irrelevant.

Comment: does this mean that ATI drivers already have Intel drivers?
Because I am sure that I have Intel HD Graphics 4000 GPU & ATI Radeon 7670m GPU.
So I should only install the drivers from ATI?

Comment: the Intel driver is only included in the drivers from Dell webpage, not when you install the driver from AMD website.